# maintain scroll position after calling a web-method

Tags: javascript, screen, coordinates, webmethod

I'm trying to open a dialog at client side.
when opening a linkbutton to open a dialog (the link is at bottom of screen and obligate
the user to scroll down the page)- a web-method is being called and returns the information to show in the dialog.
The problem is- the scroll of page returns to the top.
I have tried to save the coordinate before calling the web- method like this:

> ScreenTopCoordinate = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

and when returning from the web-method (before opening the dialog):

> document.documentElement.scrollTop = ScreenTopCoordinate;

and it works- but the user still sees a movement to the top of the page and then returning down.
Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to prevent the default action that causes action to move to the top of the screen.

```
a_function = function () {alert('foo'); return false;}
```

Or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="a_function(); return false;">anchor</a>
```

This will prevent your browser to scroll top.